# Working with functions

Tags: c++

I am writing this method that takes in 3 parameters and then outputs the result in an ordered row. I got it to that point fine, but for some reason I get a duplicate number at end of each iteration. Such as:

[image]

Here is the entire code. Hope it helps:

```
#include <iostream>
//function prototype:
int payoff(int x, int y, int z);    

//global variables:
int R1;
int R2;
int R3;
int total;

using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    cout << "R1\t R2\t R3\t\n" << endl;

    ////////////////////
    //first loop
    ////////////////////
    R1 = 1;
    R2 = 1;
    R3 = 1;
    printf("%d", payoff(R1, R2, R3));
    printf("\n");

    ////////////////////
    //second loop
    ////////////////////
    R1 = 1;
    R2 = 2;
    R3 = 1;
    printf("%d", payoff(R1, R2, R3));
    printf("\n");

    ////////////////////
    //third loop
    ////////////////////
    R1 = 1;
    R2 = 3;
    R3 = 1;
    printf("%d", payoff(R1, R2, R3));
    printf("\n");

    ////////////////////
    //fourth loop
    ////////////////////
    R1 = 2;
    R2 = 1;
    R3 = 1;
    printf("%d", payoff(R1, R2, R3));
    printf("\n");

    ////////////////////
    //fifth loop
    ////////////////////
    R1 = 2;
    R2 = 2;
    R3 = 1;
    printf("%d", payoff(R1, R2, R3));
    printf("\n");

    ////////////////////
    //sixth loop
    ////////////////////
    R1 = 2;
    R2 = 3;
    R3 = 1;
    printf("%d", payoff(R1, R2, R3));
    printf("\n");

    ////////////////////
    //seventh loop
    ////////////////////
    R1 = 3;
    R2 = 1;
    R3 = 1;
    printf("%d", payoff(R1, R2, R3));
    printf("\n");

    ////////////////////
    //eight loop
    ////////////////////
    R1 = 3;
    R2 = 2;
    R3 = 1;
    printf("%d", payoff(R1, R2, R3));
    printf("\n");

    ////////////////////
    //ninth loop
    ////////////////////
    R1 = 3;
    R2 = 3;
    R3 = 1;
    printf("%d", payoff(R1, R2, R3));
    printf("\n");

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//FUNCTIONS:
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int payoff(int R1, int R2, int R3) {
    do {
        //calculate payoff:
        total = R1;
        if (R2 < R1) {
            total = total + R2;
        } //end if
        else {
            if (R3 < R1) {
                total = total + R3;
            } //end if
            else {
                total = R1;
            } // end else
        } //end else

        if (R3 < R2) {
            total = total + (2 * R3);
        } //end if
        else {
            if (R3 < R1) {
                total = total + R3;
            } //end if
            else {
                total = R1;
            } //end else
        } //end else

        //display payoff:
        printf("%d\t %d\t %d\t payoff is %d\n", R1, R2, R3, total);

        R3++;
    } while (R3 < 4); //end do-while

    return total;
} //end function payoff
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to get rid of that pesky extra number? Thank you so much on advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return code from `payoff()` is being printed in the `printf` statements which is not want you want. You just need to call `payoff()` without the `printf`.

`printf("%d", payoff(R1, R2, R3));` calls payoff function, then outputs the value returned from the payoff() function.

So replace lines such as:

```
 printf("%d", payoff(R1, R2, R3));
```

with

```
 payoff(R1, R2, R3);
```

Comment: +1, But add to the user explanation so he could know what he did wrong.

Comment: I just noticed the printf inside of the main function, I was so focused on the method itself that I did not trace it all the way. Thank you so much I will make sure to be a bit more preceptive next time.

Comment: No worries - we've all been in that place where one cannot see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 2):

this is what happens when you insert 1,1,1 in your function:

```
printf(first loop with \n)
printf(second loop with \n)
printf(last loop with \n) //because R3 will be 4 and therefore hte while-loop will end.
```

then you will return the total to the printf-function in your main function and print the duplicate lines.

if you don't want those duplicate lines you should simple call your function and make it not return anything:

instead of this:

```
int payoff(int R1, int R2, int R3) {

do{
...
}while(r3<4);

return total;
}
```

change to this:

```
void payoff(int R1, int R2, int R3) {

do{
...
}while(r3<4);

//return total;
}
```

Then call the function not like you did:

```
printf("%d", payoff(R1, R2, R3));
```

But like this:

```
payoff(R1, R2, R3);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to show that line then remove in each loop this line:

```
printf("%d", payoff(R1, R2, R3));
```

Change it to:

```
payoff(R1, R2, R3)
```

Because it is printing a number `%d` of the result of the function, also in payoff you're already printing the results, so you don't need it to return it to the main site.

Why don't use loops?